# Retrieving data from Ajax POST in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery

I have an ajax POST like this

```
 $(document).ready(function () {

    var pcontent = document.body.innerHTML;
    var url = new URI();

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        type: "POST",
        data: { "pcontent": pcontent },
        success: function (data) {

            alert($(data).find(".right-panel").html());

        },
        complete: function () {

        },
        error: function (jqXHR, error, errorThrown) {
            if (jqXHR.status) {
                alert(jqXHR.responseText);
            } else {
                alert("Something went wrong");
            }
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

I am little confused how i could retrieve data (pcontent) that i post here in my code behind.actually in a specific class file i need to implement this logic .

Comment: I'm curious why you're posting the entire page's content (`document.body.innerHTML`) to the controller instead of particular elements. Is there a specific reason for that?

Comment: @RickLiddle:Yes i need to save a copy of current html page in my server.

Comment: I was going to post an answer, but on preview it looks like namkha87 has everything you need.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to create a controller action:

```
public class HomeController: {
     // model
     public class PDocument {
          public string pcontent {get;set;}
     }

     [HttpPost]
     public ActionResult SaveDocument(PDocument pcontent){
          // do something
          return new JsonResult() { Data = new { Success = true } };
     }
}
```

JS:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Home/SaveDocument",
    type: "POST",
    data: { "pcontent": pcontent} 
...});
```

**Note:**

- You don't need to create a model on server if set

  ```
  $.ajax({
      url: "Home/SaveDocument",
      type: "POST",
      data: pcontent
  });


  // server side

  public ActionResult SaveDocument(string pcontent){
      // do some thing
  }
  ```
- For security reason, your html must be encoded before calling ajax

In case you new to mvc, then this is a good way to start: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-controller

Comment: Can you give me an example so that i can implement this in a simple class file not with this controller and other stuff..

Comment: controller action is where you handle requests from client my friend. All you need to do is add your code in the SaveDocument action above.

Comment: ah  i am a little new to MVC.The API i am working on is built in MVC that is the only relation with me and MVC.I am afrtaid that i cant(or i dont know) create any new action class in this application.
Usually i handles these type post requests in XSLT.

Comment: it's not that complex :). check this link: http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/mvc-4/getting-started-with-aspnet-mvc4/adding-a-controller